# What's the point of "Strange Hotel" functionality in "Puzzle Spy" mobile game

Tags: puzzle-spy

I'm trying to make heads or tails of "Strange Hotel" functionality in "Puzzle Spy" mobile game.

When I click on the icon, I see a bunch of rooms? Windows? with what seems to be skins I earned; numbered 201-204, 301-304, etc....

But I don't see anything to **DO** there aside from "Dance Time" checkbox that just makes the skins move around. What am I missing? What am I supposed to do in that window? Or is that functionality purely decorative and not playable?